Transmitter parasitic drainage
I have a RF cordless calling/alarm bell which works on batteries. The receiver works with 3x AA batteries and its transmitter works with a 23A (12v) battery. The product works with their function.
The problem is that the receiver dies after a week or so. I tried changing the battery but still no use. I tested with a new battery using a current mode on multimeter and I got 0.3ma (298uA) while idle and about 10mA when button on with transmitting.
Is this idle parasitic drain usual for such transmitters? 23A battery is about 50mAh capacity and with such a idle drain at 0.3mA should completely drain about a week. Is it a bad design or maybe something shorted with the circuit when solder?

Edit: Tested Resistors 
R1-100R R2-100R  R5-115K  R6-47K  R7-12K  R9-4.7K  R11-Unsoldered  R12-4.7K  R13-1K 
Resistors looks Ok. Except R5 is 115K and the SMD mark(184) should be 180k.
Edit: I scraped the trace of VCC just after the diode and I bridged from the switch pin using a wire, bypassing the direct trace of VCC. The remote transmitter works, needs 1 second to trigger the switch (probably needs the capacitor to fully charge) but the parasitic drain is fixed . The current draw is 0uA idle when measured. As far as I'm concerned, I'm satisfied with the result.


Take another look at the receiver and transmitter characterisation in your question I think

This is a super cheap design for the purpose of low production costs. It's not in the seller's interest to optimize current consumption - they just mass market crap without a thought about building a brand or getting returning customers.

@Lundin I know that they are cheap crap but I have also seen super cheap keyfob that works for years using a CR2032 coin.  By design, the switch should close the circuit only if pressed, right?

"The receiver works with 3x AA batteries and its receiver works with a 23A (12v) battery. "
The receiver and it's receiver?

"The problem is that the receiver dies after a week or so. [...]  [it consumes] about 10mA when button on with transmitting."
The receiver? When it's transmitting? Which receiver? The receiver or the receiver?

The likely problem is a degraded/damaged component. For example the cylindrical electrolytic cap could have excess leakage or one of those SMD ceramic caps may have been cracked. A thermal camera may show which part get a bit hotter than the others. So the product you bought is defective out-of-the box and you should return it for new one, which may also be defective, so might as well ask for refund.

@MrGerber Sorry, typo. Receiver is AA type and Transmitter is 23A type. I have also made edit on main question.

@Justme I'll try testing with Capacitance mode with my multimeter and see how it goes.

@Kokachi Don't bother, it can't tell you anything useful unless you remove the caps for testing them in isolation, and even then, your multimeter likely cannot tell you the leakage. Wrong tool, wrong procedure.

@Justme You're right. Also some capacitors are in parallel. I tested for resistors (edited) and they are ok.

Looking at the circuit board you can see that VDD goes through D1 and then to the pushbutton. But it also goes up to U1 and some other components, so most likely U1 is powered all the time and an input on it senses when the button is pressed. This means there will always be some standby current being drawn.
Whether or not 0.3 mA is the normal standby current for the circuit is another question. For the battery type used it should be far less if you want the battery to last very long. It could be a problem with the device, or it could just be a poor design. It might have been designed to run on a battery with more capacity but someone is selling them with the 23A batteries. Without a schematic or any other information on the transmitter it's hard to say one way or the other.

You're right. U1 is powered all the time. This tiny 23A battery is more than twice a AA battery. So I don't think they intended to work for a short  time. I'll try to find and identify parts and trace the schematics.

@Kokachi An alkaline AA will be something like 2500 mAh, 50 times the 23A. An AA is a single 1.5 V cell, the 23A is a stack of smaller cells meant to give a higher voltage (~12V) at the expense of current and capacity.

Sorry, I meant it cost twice as much as a AA.

I jerry rigged the board and fixed the parasitic drain.
